# Web server stress testing

Tags: performance, performance-testing, stress-testing, webtest, webapplicationstresstool

I want to test my web server before it use for hosting 20 websites.

Is there any method of test procedure using any testing tool to check whether server can able to load all 20 websites/ how it performs?

Comment: Take a look on ab - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool.

Comment: Okay thanks, let me have a try on this tool